Why thank HaShem for skirting (larger) tragedy when He orchestrated the situation in the first place?
If one subscribes to a theory of hashgacha that ascribes everything to HaShem (which altho not taken by most rishonim seems to be the prevailing opinion nowadays), then why, when say someone gets sick or injured, but avoids greater sickness/injury or better yet is ultimately fully healed (eg someone that needs to bring a korban todah), or for instance is involved in a mva but comes out with minor injuries only, etc, do people thank God for it? After all, He is the one that orchestrated this tragic circumstance in the first place, and while it is nice that one wasn't hurt even worse, gratitude seems to be out of place, as if it wasn't for HaShem putting this hardship into place then there wouldn't have been any hardship at all. By analogy, if someone breaks someone else's arm should he thank him for only breaking one arm or setting the broken arm in a cast to heal it?

"If one subscribes to a theory of hashgacha that ascribes everything to HaShem" If one does not subscribe to such a theory, I think your question would be even stronger. Why thank Hashem for saving you, when you probably have no clue whether he did or not?

@MichoelR I left room for the optimist that would ascribe the tragedy to chance but the salvation to HaShem

I once heard a Mashal by the slavery in Mitzrayim.

A King sends his soldiers to battle. When the war is over, the King
returns the armies, and then there is celebration, even though it was
the King who sent the soldiers to battle. This is because sending them
to battle was not the pleasure of the King; it was necessary, and
unfortunate. However, it greatly delights the King to bring the
soldiers home.

I think we can learn from this about what you ask about as well. When Hashem brings difficulties upon a person, He is only doing it because it is necessary, and ultimately for the good (which, when Moshiach comes, we will thank Him and bless Him for too). He does not take "pleasure" in it, so to speak - the opposite. Hashem suffers along with the person. However, when the "job is done", Hashem then heals the person with great love and delight, so to speak, and of course we thank Him for that.

If suffering is always correlated to sin then all suffering is just and precise, and if anything one should be glad for the suffering itself, but to thank God for not doing more than necessary? Why would HaShem inflict more than what is necessary for sin therapy? That would be cruel and unjust . . per your answer there should be no need to thank God for not overdoing it . .

@Nahum before I answer - do you have a precedent in halacha or hashkafa that when we break 1 hand, we should thank Hashem for not breaking both hands?

Just the general sentiment one hears when tragedy strikes. "Thank God, it could have been worse" is very common.

@Nahum חיב אדם לברך על הרעה כשם שהוא מברך על הטובה... בכל מדה ומדה שהוא מודד לך הוי מודה לו במאד מאד

Yes, I am aware of that. That adds up, but for not more than necessary? Not so much.

... בכל מדה ומדה
